# Solving Matrix elements by using while iteration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a known 5X6 sized **M** matrix, and a 6x1 sized **K** matrix which its 4 elements unknowns and two knowns. **P** matrix obtained by multiplication of these two matrices and has different 5 elements all which function of an **x** variable. Altogether, there are 5 equations and 5 unknowns (four from the K, and one from the P(which is x))

`M[5X6]*K[6X1]=P[5X1]

 P=[constant*x, constant2*x, constant3*x, constant4*x, constant5*x)`

How can I obtain a while iteration in Matlab to solve these 5 unknowns? Is this possible in Matlab with the while or for loop?         `

Comment: Do you have a closed definition of your problem?

Comment: Will you be happy with any solution to the problem or do you insist on using `while` or `for`? (I don't see any reason to do so)

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-a-system-of-linear-equations.html

Comment: Yohai, would be great if I can learn to do with while/loop iterations since I believe this will give me a very good base for the future problems and provide flexibility to construct very different things. But, if you can suggest some other methods, I would appreciate that as well. Masoud thank you for this one, I checked this out before.                                                           Yvon, I don't have any numbers, I am just creating myself some problems actually. Lets say M is identity matrix, and K=[1;2;a;b;c;d].